# Does all the custom code added through the backend editors just get pushed into the database?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, implementation, custom-wordpress-pages

When you add custom css code through the "custom css" fields in the backend editors along with using plugins for adding custom scripts, do those lines of code just get saved to the database(with the exception of the WP file editor) and get called on page load? Are no files being generated or edited when adding custom code through those avenues of approach? I've currently taken on the task of helping with redesign a WordPress website through some volunteer work and am trying to get a better idea on the different approaches to customizing WordPress. Excuse my ignorance if I may be looking at things the wrong way.

The redesign was already created on Figma and the site uses Elementor so I implemented the new header and footer through Elementor and it came out pretty nicely. Director asked me if I could hard code the header and footer to help with optimizations and that he had someone do it on the old design. I started to explore how the previous person went about doing it and it seems that he just added the php code with inline html through the the child theme and added the css through the editor on the custom css field with the native page editor. There was no previous documentation so it was a pain trying to gather all this information. Now I copied over the child theme and moved the css from the custom css field to the style.css file but now running into multiple issues. I know I need to scour the WP and Elementor docs to make sure I follow proper conventions. I feel like it's just more difficult since they have a slew of plugins for customization and scripts and not much documentation on how things were implemented.
I was going to recommend at our meeting with just sticking with Elementor for the current redesign plan and push that to production and I can work on getting a better understanding of the theme files while taking stock and documenting everything. As for optimizations I would rather start with reducing the amount of plugins(many unused and not updated) we have because that probably affects performance more than anything. I just want to make sure I'm going about things the correct way.

**tl:dr **
Present the idea at a meeting to just use what we have for a redesign project and take a different approach for optimizations rather than what the Director thinks about optimizing the website.